# Antd Datepicker: Add Extra Button to footer or Change "Now" functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I have a Date and Time picker that I want to further customize. I want to add an extra button that allows the user to jump to an existing request date and so that they only have to input the time, but I don't like the way the extra footer looks. Is there a way to **move this button to the same footer as the OK button**?

Or maybe change the "Now" functionality to jump to specified date instead of today? I've been able to change the text but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

I know that there is a `panelRender` property on AntD Datepickers but I can't find any examples using it and am having trouble figuring it out.

```
<Form.Item name="requestDateTime">
    <DatePicker format="YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A"
        locale={{
            ...locale,
            lang: {
                ...locale.lang,
                 now: "Request Date"
            }
        }}        
        renderExtraFooter={() => 
            <Button onClick={()=> { 
                form.setFieldsValue({["requestDateTime"]: moment(initialRequestDate)})}
            }> Request Date</Button>
        }
        showTime={{ defaultValue: moment('00:00:00', 'h:mm A') }}>
    </DatePicker>
</Form.Item>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't think there's a straightforward answer here, unless you want to switch over to the range picker and set preset ranges, but then you'd have to work around the range logic to fit your use case which can be messy. Alternatively, you could also move the request date button outside the date picker dropdown, and when you press the button it opens and prefills the picker with the requested datetime.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple. You do this:

```
renderExtraFooter={() => (
    <h4
       onClick={() => console.log('test')}
       style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 20 }}
    >
       test
    </h4>
)}
```